# System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Split' And no extension method "Split"

Tags: c#, split

I've seen the previous post that an array can't be split, but have no clue what to do in order to bypass the error.

```
private DataTable SplitStringInto(string fldName, string txt, params string[] splitters) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(fldName, typeof(string));
        foreach (string s in splitters.Split(StringSplitOptions.None)) { //error appear here
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        s});
        }
        
        return dt;
    }
```

Am trying to move this Vb code to C#

Comment: Your code is not equivalent. `string` does have a `Split` function - `string[]` does not, though.

Comment: This code did not use a params array at first, just a single string.  Since it now uses string[] you no longer need String.Split().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, probably, want to split *text* - `txt` with `splitters` provided (say, `","`, `";"`, `"\t"`):

```
private DataTable SplitStringInto(string fldName, string txt, params string[] splitters) {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add(fldName, typeof(string));

  foreach (string s in txt.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.None)) 
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { s });

  return dt;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
DataTable result = SplitStringInto("myField", "line1;line2,line3", ";", ",", "\t");
```